# Padding between TDs in email template

Tags: html, html-email, email-templates

I have written an email template, its only a set of images with hyperlinks. Its working good on my browser, but when I send it through email, it gets broken due to unnecessary padding between tds.
[image]

This is how it should render. But what I see:
[image]

And when I inspected it: 
[image]

You see the unnecessary padding? Here's the code:

```html
<html><head>
<title>Email Template</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (594bfefd1385a.jpeg) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1004" height="577" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <a href="https://www.thetwistedbit.com/collections/ego-7-tall-boots#utm_source=hypermail&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=ego7&amp;utm_term=ego7"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68d7e313.gif" width="231" height="173" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="8" rowspan="5">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68dbb799.gif" width="411" height="445" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="5">
   <a href="https://www.thetwistedbit.com/#utm_source=hypermail&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=ego7"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68db1f3f.gif" width="361" height="163" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="163" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68dd8c60.gif" width="361" height="105" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="10" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="8">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68de43fb.gif" width="231" height="403" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="95" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e02a9f.gif" width="164" height="177" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/28+N+Central+Ave,+Hartsdale,+NY+10530/@41.0195605,-73.7994692,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2948a2925d351:0x84bfe9e32b3fb392!8m2!3d41.0195565!4d-73.7972805"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e23617.gif" width="72" height="73" alt=""></a></td>
  <td rowspan="5">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e25d27.gif" width="125" height="244" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="73" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="4">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e4689f.gif" width="72" height="171" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="104" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="5">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e47c27.gif" width="42" height="131" alt=""></td>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheTwistedBitSaddlery/"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e6685e.png" width="51" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="5">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e677fe.gif" width="281" height="2" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/EquestrianStyle/"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e6685e.png" width="51" height="52" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68e877be.gif" width="150" height="67" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="4">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68ea96be.gif" width="89" height="129" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/thetwistedbit/"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68eab5fe.gif" width="51" height="50" alt=""></a></td>
  <td rowspan="4">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68ec9295.gif" width="15" height="129" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.instagram.com/TheTwistedBit/"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68ecb9a6.gif" width="50" height="50" alt=""></a></td>
  <td rowspan="4">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68eeadad.gif" width="76" height="129" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="50" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68eebd4d.gif" width="51" height="79" alt=""></td>
  <td rowspan="3">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68f15f75.gif" width="51" height="79" alt=""></td>
  <td rowspan="3">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68f16f15.gif" width="50" height="79" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68f37e75.gif" width="51" height="79" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="15" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68f36aec.gif" width="62" height="64" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="3">
   <a href="https://www.thetwistedbit.com/#utm_source=hypermail&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=ego7"><img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68f589ec.gif" width="285" height="25" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="25" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68f5a15d.gif" width="285" height="39" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="1" height="39" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="231" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="42" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="51" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="89" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="51" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="15" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="50" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="76" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="37" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="14" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="62" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="88" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="72" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://thetwistedbit.net/imagehosting/5360/594eb68fb3b0a.gif" width="125" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->

</body></html>
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Email templating is a complicated world due to the many different email clients out there and the ways they are trying to keep their users safe and happy. Before anyone might possible be able to help you out with this, you would have to add some info on the email client used to view the email, either offline (e.g. outlook, thunderbird) or online (e.g. gmail, yahoo).. and even then, if anyone is able to help you out in this specific scenario, it's probably still not going to look great in other email clients.

Comment: You're probably best off using [Mailchimp and one of their templates](https://mailchimp.com/features/email-templates/), they take care of the mess..

Comment: A mess indeed but there is a simple fix. Havent seen the code i assume.

Comment: @Syfer, indeed I haven't looked at the code, I realise additional spacing around images has usually to do with `display:block` (no need to look at the code for that :)), just trying to give some sensible advice since I figured, just like you, that this is probably OP's first email template, and I wondered if OP realises what mess he's getting himself into..

Comment: All good, I note out things he should not do for emails. There quiet a lot of things but I think those should suffice to over come really basic mistakes. Now let's hope my answer isn't late lol

Answer (score 1):

I take it this is the first email you have built? It is not padding, its the display block that is missing from the images. Use the below code for all images in the html:

```
 style="display:block;" hspace="0" vspace="0" alt="" border="0"
```

**Note:** Since you have so many colspan and rowspan the template might not work properly in some email clients. The above code will ensure all your images are sitting flush against each other.

A word of advice not to be taken lightly:

1. Never do Save for web from Photoshop. It creates table that is not fixable most of the time.
2. Don't use col span. Some email email clients don't like it.
3. Only image emails will have delivery problem, general rule is to have 70/30 (some day 60/40) to get best results.
4. Use media queries or Gmail fix or your emails will look really messed up in Gmail apps.

Let me know if the above fix works.

Cheers

Comment: I fixed it, all I did was removed all the colspans and rowspans. I sliced in such a way that I will have a balanced table. And that literally worked for me in every email client. Although it went from 27 slices to 103 but it works finally. haha

Comment: I wouldn't recommend 103. Try to keep it down. I can give you a grid if you like. Why so many slices?

Comment: If this was the right answer please accept it as the correct answer.